# How does a resistance connected in series with a zener diode but parallel to the load resistance affect the output voltage?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, voltage, semiconductor-physics

[image]

The breakdown voltage of A is $6V$ and that of B is $4V$

In this question let's assume that the input voltage is $f(t)$, a linear function of time. It's quite obvious that $V_{\text{output}}=f(t)$ when the input is lesser than $4\,\text{V}$ and $V_{\text{output}}$ is independent of $f(t)$ above $6\,\text{V}$. My question is what will happen between $4\,\text{V}$ and $6\,\text{V}$?

I think $V_{\text{output}}= f(t)$ since the current can still pass through zener diode A, but my textbook says that the slope should decrease within this interval. How is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author of that textbook question did a really bad job (if you didn't omit information or make transcription mistakes).

The way the schematic is given, $V_{in} = V_o$ always holds, as they are directly connected. No matter whether $V_{in}$ is below 4V, above 6V or whatever.

If the components are assumed to be "ideal" (what textbooks typically do), this question leads to physically impossible situations.

If $V_{in}$ were an ideal voltage source, above 6V, you'd get an infinite current through the idealized 6V zener diode, which is physically impossible, and in any real-world experiment would blow up that component.

So, to make this experiment physically possible, you have to assume some non-ideal, real-world properties of the components.

Assuming some finite impedance of the voltage source, which can be understood as a series resistor at the top left, would lead to results like those given in the textbook, but nothing about the non-ideal parameters of the components seems to be given with the question.

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear, please take a look at it again.

Comment: @Sunaina you still haven't included anything about the (Thevenin) resistance of the source in the problem statement.